# Как в emacs включить разные цвета для скобок?

Tags: ide, любой-язык, emacs

подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли в emacs включить разные цвета для разных пар скобок? Если да, - как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
M-x package-install RET rainbow-delimiters RET
```

https://github.com/Fanael/rainbow-delimiters